# Knife SSH attribute not working

Tags: ssh, chef-infra, knife

Im confused by the `knife ssh` command. According to the docs you can pass the `-a` flag if your node does not have a FQDN or ipaddress attribute set. Also, if you want to override those attributes. I'm running this to test `knife ssh` on a local VM:

```
  $ knife ssh "role:webserver" "sudo chef-client" -x someusername -a 192.168.14.141
```

The error i receive:

**FATAL: 1 node found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the connection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribute.**

I am running **Chef 11.4.0**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-a` argument actually means the name of the attribute which contains the IP address of the node, if the `node[:fqdn]` or `node[:ipaddress]` attributes are  not set.

For example I have the openstack ohai plugin installed the public IPv4 address is stored in `node[:openstack][:public_ipv4]` I would write the knife ssh command like:

```
$ knife ssh "role:webserver" "sudo chef-client" -x user -a openstack_public_ipv4
```

where `openstack_public_ipv4` is the search attribute format to match the `node[:openstack][:public_ipv4]` attribute.